# set the column order while uploading a document in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

am having a requirement to create a power shell script which set the column order  from mandatory fiels to optional fields in the document  library, when i try to upload a  document.

if i elaborate, i am  uploading a  doc to the doc lib. which has the below columns:

columnA -   [choice field  - mandatory ]

columnB -   [lookup field  - mandatory ]

columnC -   [single line of text  - optional ]

columnD -   [choice field  - optional ]

columnE -   [choice field  - mandatory ]

now when  the end user uploads a   document in my doc lib, i would like to see the mandatory columns takes up the top order and then optional fields.

columnA

columnB

columnE

columnC

columnD

so, is there any script, through which i can set the mandatory columns which will be coming in top and the optional fields as next order

Comment: Are these fields in a content type?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nadeem. Yes, These columns are coming from content type.Also i tried to write few lines of coe.  but it did not work.

Comment: $list = $web.Lists[$abc]              $list.Title
           $result=New-Object system.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType]
$ContentType="Memo"{$ctype = $list.contenttypes[$ContentType] $newFieldOrderfromxml = "column3, column1,column4,column7,column6.column2"
 $newfieldorder = $newFieldOrderfromxml.Split(',')
$ctype.FieldLinks.Reorder($newFieldOrder)
$ctype.update()
$rresult.Add($ctype)
              }
              $list.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $result
              $list.RootFolder.Update()

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample PowerShell Code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://aissp2013/sites/TestSite
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
$contentType = $list.ContentTypes | where {$_.Name –eq "MyTestCT"}
$ctArray = "Title","ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnD","ColumnC"
$contentType.FieldLinks.Reorder($ctArray)
$contentType.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope Nadeem's solution will work for you. In case you face some issues with it you can do the same using UI.

1. Go to Library Settings
2. Click your content type under "Content Types"
3. Click the "Column order"

Change the columns order as you want.

Regards,